# Google Cloud Functions Gen2: Unable to pull Python image from europe-west4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We are experiencing difficulties with our Google Cloud Functions using the `Python 3.10` runtime in the `europe-west4` region.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations), the region should be supported in Google Cloud Functions Gen2, but during build the image can't be pulled.

Anyone else also experiencing this?

[Error pulling Python image from europe-west4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRNDF.png)

Comment: Having the same issue as you, I'm not able to get any response anywhere from Google and their status page even says that west4 has no support at all for functions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been reported now on the status page.

https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/MGQTanrU9ETiKdQM8MxH

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can confirm the issue has been resolved!